# Create a basic chat bot from the command line

Tags: java, loops

**I have tried everywhere else to get help with my homework question, I really just need some help with this one. I'm supposed to have a no-Scanner ChatBot with:**

-If the user entered nothing at the command line, show Nothing to say?

-If the user entered some variation of how are you today? show Fine, but could use some more power. As long as the input has the word "are" before the word "you", print this message. Make your program smart enough to accept variations of these words (see output).

-If the user entered some variation of what is your favorite something? Display something? I'm only interested in transistors.

-In all other cases, show I didn't understand that.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    if(args.length == 0)
        System.out.println("Nothing to say?");
    else
    {
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
        for(String data: args)

            input.append(data).append(" ");

        input = new StringBuilder(input.toString().toLowerCase());

        int indexOfAre = input.indexOf("are");
        int indexOfYou = input.indexOf("you");
        int indexOfFavourite = input.indexOf("favourite");

        if( indexOfAre != -1 && indexOfYou != -1 && indexOfAre < indexOfYou)

            System.out.println("Fine, but could use some more power.");

        else if(indexOfFavourite != -1)
        {
            int spaceIndex = input.indexOf(" ", indexOfFavourite);

            int qmIndex = input.indexOf("?", spaceIndex);

            String str = input.substring(spaceIndex+1,qmIndex);

            System.out.println(str.trim()+"? I'm only interested in transistors.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("I didn't understand that.");
    }
}
}
```

The transistors answer doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why, please help

Thank you :)

Comment: We probably need to know what "some variation" means.  The simplest way is to do it just like the first requirement.

Comment: It means capital or lowercase or if the command line input is something like this: what do I have to say to FIGURE OUT your FAVORITE3 soda?

Comment: _The transistors answer doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why_ – [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63045353/edit) your question to include a specific (input) example when that case is not working, but you expect it to be actually working.

Comment: _It means capital or lowercase_ – if variations include upper- and lowercase then you want to "normalize" the user's input to either all uppercase or lowercase before checking that normalized input against your strings in your code.

Comment: Also – _Welcome to Stack Overflow_ – Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular ***[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)***.